# Procedure listed in package body but not spec

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm fairly new to Oracle, ok VERY new - but I'm learning. I have a package that compiled without errors. When I open the body (using TOAD), I can see a procedure, but that same procedure does not show up in the spec. What would cause this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That simply means that the procedure is private.

It is rather common to have procedures and functions in the package body that are not in the package spec.  Those methods are only visible to other methods in the package body; they are private methods.  That tends to be a useful method to separate the public API of the package from the private implementation details and/or to create methods that you don't want code outside the package to inadvertently call.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense.